# Difference between Netty and Undertow

Tags: java, spring-boot, netty, undertow, reactor-netty

I am new to Netty and undertow trying to understand why we use netty instead of undertow , Performance wise which one is better to use

Comment: If one would be flat out superior, only one would exist, wouldn't it? The question is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: [Undertow now uses Netty](http://undertow.io/blog/2019/04/15/Undertow-3.html). The programming model is different - Netty is low-level framework for "...development of network applications such as protocol servers and clients" whereas Undertow is strictly a web server with (optional) support for Servlet 4.0.

Comment: Performance wise which one is better to use ?

Comment: At best, your question is like "which is better: chocolate or vanilla?"  But in this case, as gears pointed out, Undertow effectively *IS* Netty.  So the only real question is "Q: Which API do you feel more comfortable programming?"  If you're comfortable coding your application to Netty ... then you probably don't need the additional overhead of adding Undertow.  'Hope that helps...

Comment: @Anitha : Given that Undertow uses Netty underneath, Netty performance will be higher than Undertow performance.